# A Continuous Choice of $k$-Subspaces of a Vector Space Gives a Continuous Choice of Bases

Tags: general-topology, continuity, quotient-spaces, grassmannian

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$
The Grassmannian $G_k(\R^n)$ as a topoplogical space is defined in the following way:

Let $F_k(\R^n)$ be the collection of all the linearly independent lists of size $k$ of $\R^n$. For two members $\mathbf v=(\mathbf v_1, \ldots, \mathbf v_k)$ and $\mathbf u=(\mathbf u_1,\ldots, \mathbf u_k)$ of $F_k(\R^n)$ write $\mathbf u\sim \mathbf v$ iff $\text{span}(\mathbf u)=\text{span}(\mathbf v)$. It is clear that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Note that $F_k(\R^n)$ can be thought of all the set of all the $k\times n$ matrices having rank $k$. So it is an open subspace of $\R^{nk}$.

We define $G_k(\R^n)$ as the quotient $F_k(\R^n)/\sim$ in the quotient topology.

> Suppose we have a continuous function $f:\R\to G_k(\R^n)$.
>   Can we choose a continuous function $F:\R\to F_k(\R^n)$ such that $f(t)=\text{span}(F(t))$ for all $t$?

Loosely, suppose we have a continuous choice of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\R^n$, then can we have a continuous choice of bases of these $k$-subspaces?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Basically this works because $\mathbb R$ is simply connected.  See e.g.
 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Lifting_properties).

Comment: I am not familiar with algebraic topology. Could you please elaborate on your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Basically,  you can make the choice in a sufficiently small interval, and then go on to the next interval.

Comment: Visiting this thread again, your suggestion seems to be that $F_k(\mathbf R^n)\to G_k(\mathbf R^n)$ is a covering projection. But this is not true since the dimensions of $F_k(\mathbf R^n)$ and $G_k(\mathbf R^n)$ are different. Please correct me if I am misinterpreting your comment.